Combining mechanical and electronic components for controlled switching in a 230 V single-phase grid system
I would like to ask a question regarding the combined use of a mechanical switch with electronic components.
I need a voltage relay that can detect undervoltage or overvoltage in a 230 V single-phase grid-connected load (based on my definition).
When it detects either condition, it should activate the gate signal of a thyristor.
The thyristor will then initiate the mechanical switch (circuit breaker) at the voltage zero-crossing point, reducing the losses in the mechanical switch to near zero.
Then the thyristor is removed from the circuit, and the switch continues its operation. The thyristor is used only for zero-crossing voltage identification.
Is this possible, and which components can be used to achieve it?

Welcome! "The thyristor is used only for zero-crossing voltage identification." Please show how.

I would like to ask a question ... there is no reason to say that  ... this is a question and answer site ... a question is required

With a microcontroller or a PLC, with analog inputs ,you control the level of the line voltage. If there is a relative variation in the peak amplitude greater than that established during programming, the thyristor is triggered.

How can I get Analog signal exchange between microcontroller  or PLC while the input signal is AC 230 v.
